# How to specify a c++ Variant return type in a c# dllimport

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I have a C++ function in a dll :

```
VARIANT __stdcall CallBlah(LPCSTR sA, LPCSTR sB, LPCSTR sC, LPCSTR sD, LPCSTR sE, LPCSTR sF)
{
    char *srtnstring = NULL

    ... do stuff ...

    _bstr_t bstrt(srtnstring);
    return _variant_t(bstrt)
}
```

and I am trying to use this i  a c# app but I am having an issue with the Variant return type. My c# import is:

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern IntPtr callBlah(
   string A,
   string B,
   string C,
   string D,
   string E,
   string F);
```

but when I run the c# app I get an unbalanced stack Exception. What should the return type be for the dllImport c# signature?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can marshall a `VARIANT*` to an `IntPtr`, not sure if you can actually marshall a copy.

Comment: If you can change the C++ code, then it would be much easier to replace the variant with a simpler type.

Comment: Marshal it as `object`

Comment: This is a 3rd party dll and so I cannot change it.

If I do change the return time to object I get a `PInvoke restriction:cannot return variants.`

Comment: Then I suggest that the best approach is to wrap the broken DLL with another that is interop friendly.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should use StringBuilder on C# side instead of string. Second of all you should create class in C# that is compatible with c++ VARIANT and then marshall it as an object.

Comment: I cannot see how I can create a compatible class as it is a variant and so can hold anything.

Comment: Here you are: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221627(v=vs.85).aspx

That's why you shouldn't use this type. You should rather read about COM in C# as VARIANT is COM type.

Comment: @Steveip This answer is bogus. Ignore it.

Comment: How is my answer bogus?